# Header messed up in custom page template wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I created a custom page template, here the link http://goo.gl/UFgzGQ, but I noticed that the style of header is messed up only on that page.

How to fix this?

Here's the css

```
.header-wrap .search-icon {
float: right;
position: relative;
margin-top: -32px;
line-height: 6;
margin-right: -30px;
border-left: 1px solid #ECECEC;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0 20px;
}

.header-wrap .ak-search {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF;
display: none;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Actually its not the **CSS** which causing the misalignment or misplacing the *search-icon*, its your **DOM** viz the main culprit as:

your maine-page screen:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      ....
```

you can see that it has perfectly defined header with `doctype` whereas in your inner-page:

[image]

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
         .........
```

there are some broken code viz the main-culprit and causing the issue.

Comment: @User014019 what's not working ? what you're seeking ?

Comment: the search is still messed up

Comment: @User014019 check the screenshot in my answer, it not what you want ?

Comment: i can't check the screen shot because the url is blocked in our server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90771/discussion-between-vivekkupadhyay-and-user014019).